# issues with button in uiimage in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uiimage

I have problem in xcode, I'm trying to add button in the image but the position comes in the different positions from iPhones screens

Here is the picture from my storyboard:

http://ya-techno.com/up//uploads/images/yaTechno-cb6317a232.png

and here are the preview from others screens :

iPhone with 3.5 and 4 inch screen:

http://ya-techno.com/up//uploads/images/yaTechno-51f7ca836e.png

and this iPhone with 4.7 and 5.5 inches:

http://ya-techno.com/up//uploads/images/yaTechno-0a9210e0e5.png

I'm using the auto layout.

help :(

Comment: remove the autolayout and check

Comment: @CoolCracker I tri before it killed my design in all screens

Comment: whenever u change/update your UIelements - remove the old constraints and add the new constarints

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks, I have done that also and still didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use auto layout and there's no other way unless you write a very ugly code where you hard code the center for those buttons for each screen size!

I recommend reading about auto layout, it is little weird to start but you will get used to it after a while

here's a very good tutorial which helped me a lot http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1